Does MinGW-w64 source code need to be cross-compiled in a system that already has GNU utilities?
I have once compiled emacs from source on Debian to make use of novel features that relied on some flags that needed to be used during compilation of the source code. Having also installed Gentoo on a old PC I began to appreciate software built from source code (on limited hardware such as that old PC I got the impression that compiling the OS and applications from source code made them more responsive than if I had simply downloaded the binary executable files. I believe that building from source creates a executable that is better tailored to the instructions that are available to each processor, i.e., if the available binary was compiled in a system that could perform AVX2 instructions if you tried to run this executable on a old CPU that did not have AVX2 instructions, it would first try to run these instructions, it would find that the CPU doesn't support those instructions and then it would run those instructions by software emulation, or something, making the executable slow. I don't know if this is exactly what happens, but I did experience a better performance on source compiled programs in contrast to the binary pre-packaged versions on that old and performance limited PC.).
As I am using a new but rather performance bound mobile PC, I think I would rather compile MinGW-w64 from source (I am not sure if this would make the result more performant, but if by doing this I could get a smaller sized executable that would be good also).
But, as far as I can see, from guides such as https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/mingw-w64-doc/howto-build/mingw-w64-howto-build.txt, it appears that to compile MinGW-w64 you would need to have a working MinGW-w64 installation (such as the binary executable that is available from the site (which was probably cross-compiled from a working Linux distribution, or at least had it's first version be cross-compiled).
Is this correct? And does building an executable from source on a specific PC really makes the executable be custom tailored for that specific CPU and hence more performant? (Even if minimally so) Or was my perception with running Gentoo with software executables compiled from source on that old PC just a placebo like response?

You likely don't need an existing MinGW installation when building on Linux. But you do need a linux compiler, binutils, etc (so your title doesn't match the question?). You'd only need existing MinGW to build on Windows. As for performance difference, measure it (compile a compiler yourself, compare its performance against a prebuilt one in some distro).

@HolyBlackCat Yes, I meant that to compile MinGW-w64 from source on Windows you would need a previous MinGW installation that already works. It wouldn't make sense to require MinGW on Linux since it already has the GNU utilities from the outset. The title asks basically if MinGW-w64 was written in such a way as to be compliable by native windows available compilers such as MSVC or if it could only be compiled by GNU tools, which makes the origin of MinGW-w64 to be a cross-compiled program that was originally compiled on a Linux system.

I doubt it can be compiled with MSVC, but I didn't check.

To compile an optimized version of MinGW-w64 for a specific system there are several things that come into play:

The system you build on needs to have the necessary tools to build it (GNU utilities, autoconf tools, a working MinGW-w64/GCC compiler, ...)
To optimize for the best runtime environment you need to think of the target system. So if you're cross-compiling, this will be the (minimum supported) architecture of the Windows system(s) you want to support. Typically this may involve compiler flags like -march and -mtune.
Specifically for MinGW-w64 there is also the configure option --with-default-win32-winnt to set the specific (minimum) Windows version you want to support. As newer Windows versions may add to the API more efficient functions may be used by MinGW-w64 or the software you are compiling.

